# C# how calculate my price in my listbox

Tags: c#, database, listbox

I am a beginner and trying to create a simple inventory for our future business :)

How can I do to this problem ?

I want to calculate the price when I click every button to my listbox.

**Example:**

When I add items and the price is `6` he display to the bottom (Total) `6` and when I add another and the price is `7` is added to `6` so the total will `13` what can I do to this scenario can I use `foreach` or something or I revise my code ? help guys thank you :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGdBs.png)

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "                 " + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "                                                      " + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + "                        " + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());

    }
    label7.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

and I cannot deduct when I void the list of transaction

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        sum -= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `int sum = 0;` inside button click event. Therefore, everytime you click on button, Sum will be set to default 0.

set `int sum = 0;` as global declaration and then try.

Something like below:

```
int sum = 0;
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 0)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "                 " + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "                                                      " + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + "                        " + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());

        }
        label7.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: hmmm that's why he can't receive by the way thanks to you sir @maulik kansara it solve ^_^ thanks a lot ^^

Comment: and another problem sir when i void the list of transaction he can't deduct

Comment: private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
                sum -= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            } 
        }

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do using LINQ.

```
using System.Linq; //import this namespace
//...
//...

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "                 " + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "                                                      " + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + "                        " + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
    }
    label7.Text = listBox1.Items.OfType<int>().ToArray().Sum().ToString();
}
```

You don't have to keep track of the items added or removed from the listbox in a separate variable- `sum`. Just use below LINQ sum() operation on your listBox whenever you want to sum the values.

```
listBox1.Items.OfType<int>().ToArray().Sum()
```

Comment: i solve i forget to declare label.text in the another button thats hahaha :D thankyou so much sirs <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class, for example, it could be Item and add some rows to it.

```
class Item 
{
    public static List<Item> Inventory = new List<Item>();

    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 Price { get; set; }
    public String ItemName { get; set; }

    private static Int32 NextId { get; set; } = 0;
    private static Int32 TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public Item(Int32 price, String name) 
    {
        this.Price = price;
        this.ItemName = name;   
        this.Id = NextId;   

        Item.Inventory.Add(this);
        Item.TotalPrice += price;

        Item.NextId++;
        // add to listbox or anything
        // like listBox1.Items.Add($"{this.Id} | {this.ItemName} / {this.Price}");
    }

    public static Int32 GetTotalPrice()
    {
        return Item.TotalPrice;
    }

    public static void RemoveItem(Int32 Id) 
    { 
        foreach ( Item _item in Item.Inventory )
        {
            if(_item.Id.Equals(Id)) 
            {
                Item.Inventory.Remove(_item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To deduct the amount based on selected row from the list, try this:

```
ListBox.SlectedObjectCollection TheSelectedItem = new ListBox.SlectedObjectCollection(listBox1);

TheSelectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItems; 

int sum = 0;
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   //also ensure that the row is selected before clicking the button that's the only way the SelectedIndex click event will fire, pass the selected row value.
if(listBox1.TheSelectedItem.Count != 0)
{
   while (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
     {   
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);        
        sum -= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToSt‌​ring()); 
      }           
  }
     label7.Text = sum.ToString();         
}
```